# ASP.NET MVC 5 failed to make the jQuery run

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have really strange problem that when I include this src

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

the jQuery run successfully but the website navbar behave in strange why check it here when you click and link in the dropdown menu that part of the website is loaded under the current page and the hole website crash

```
http://www.school.somee.com/chapter/select/3/math
```

When I remove that `src`, the navbar works fine, but the jQuery failed although it sends the right data to the controller and and data returned but just failed

My ajax code:

```
    <script >
    var appMaster = {
        menuToggler: function () {
            // Menu Toggler
            $('#menuToggler').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                /* Act on the event */
                $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
            });
        },
        updateVedio: function (id) {
            alert("list is clicked");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/chapter/getLesson',
                data: { Id: id },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("jQuery success");
                    $.each(data, function (i, lesson) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            $('#theText').text(lesson.Text);
                            $('#theVedio').attr('src', "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + lesson.Value + "?autoplay=1");

                        } else {

                            $('#theMatherial').attr('href', lesson.Text);
                        }
                    })
                    $('#theVedio').load();
                    $('#theText').load();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("jQuery failed");
                }
            });
        }
  }
  </script>

  <!-- Call functions on document ready -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Call Menu Toggler
        appMaster.menuToggler();
        // Example Call anotherFunction
        $(".main-nav li").click(function () {
            appMaster.updateVedio($(this).data('id'));
        });
    });
  </script>
```

this jQuery suppose to be triggered after the click on item in dropdown like this

```
 <ul class="main-nav">
            <li data-id="2" ><a href="">kmp</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Are you sure that you need jquery mobile and not vanilla full jquery?

Comment: no there is no error in the console and i am not sure if i need jquery mobile i have tried alot of other but this is the only one that works , how to add the full jquery

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jquery mobile, use normal jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when i use this the jQuery failed although the id send to controller is correct but it goes to the error function

Comment: plese log to console your error      console.log(data);

Comment: `XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location `

Comment: and then a really long address also this warning

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Looks like the problem in your API call. You need to add to question your backend code

Comment: i am really sorry can you explain more

Comment: provide more info how is working your /chapter/getLesson method

Comment: just JsonResult function that takes the id and get the data from database

Comment: that XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location error is on every page in the whole website